# Well-posedness of Navier-Stokes equation

Tags: pde, fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, numerics

Before running a simulation for turbulence (e.g Rayleigh-Benard Convection), how do we check for well-posedness of Navier-Stokes with other equations for a given boundary condition??

Can someone point to any reference to read on this topic??

Comment: What do you mean by "other equations".

Comment: I meant energy and other advection-diffusion equations. I only want to get the general idea wrt how this kind of initial analysis is done.

Comment: Compressible or incompressible?

Comment: I imagine you know that you'll get a million dollars if you can show well-posedness of just the N-S equation by itself. Adding anything else will only make things more complicated!

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Incompressible

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I know about the prize. I just wanted to know, how do numerical analysis guys work through it. How do they convince themselves about a numerical solution?

Comment: @user162281 -- we generally assume that the N-S equations are well posed, even though nobody can prove it. (Actually, to be more precise: There are good indications to believe that the N-S equations are in fact not well posed, but that among all solutions, one can pick one that is "physically reasonable" and only one; there are also good indications that all "reasonable" numerical schemes converge to it.)

Comment: You wrote "incompressible" but you've accepted an answer that deals with compressible flow.

Comment: @David Ketcheson While I usually deal with incompressible problems, the answer was an example of an analysis that I was looking for and is part of the answer. But you are right, I assumed a similar analysis will be possible for incompressible N-S.

Comment: @Wolgang Bangerth That is interesting to know. Can u point me to any references to study more about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following paper gives a good overview of well-posedness for the compressible Navier Stokes equations.

https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10915-016-0303-9.pdf

The basic building block is the energy method, where you linearize the equations, then left multiply with the primitive variables, and then integrate. This gives you a norm which you check for stability. The number and form of boundary conditions can be determined from the eigenvalues of the boundary operator.

This gives a necessary condition for well-posedness, and other equations can be similarly treated. However, I am not sure if this is sufficient. There are often other norms that can be used such as entropy, but the above approach seems to be a robust recipe.

Comment: Thank you, sir. This is what I was looking for. Thanks again. Can you share more literature with more deeper analysis relating to well-posedness problem? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Deeper analysis is often is much more mathematical. Maybe that question would be more suitable for math stackexchange.

Comment: Regarding sufficiency, under the assumption of smooth solutions this approach is sufficient to ensure boundedness of solutions by the localisation, linearisation and Duhamel principles. The energy estimate alone is not sufficient to establish existence and uniqueness globally and for all times however